Do statistical/probability urn models have any applications beyond the classroom?
I am learning about the Polya Urn problem (e.g. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Urn_problem). To me it seems that these kinds of problems are very useful for teaching students about probability. But I was just wondering if these problems have any applications in the real world?
For example, we learn about regression models and regression models are also used in the medical world and economics.
But do these kinds of Urn models ever come up? Do we ever model anything as an urn? Are they use in the background of some other models (ex: used to take samples from a posterior distributions)? Or are they just purely theoretical teaching examples?

Statistical mechanics comes to mind where this kind of exercise leads to physical insights

Urn schemes are used in many fields. There is a fine book on this: Pólya Urn Models.

I'm tempted to quip that "no, those are invented only to torture students."  But when one considers that those models include--and generalize--simple random sampling with and without replacement, their importance becomes more evident.

Good question, +1. I added the [tag:references] tag, since answers with actual references would be most helpful.

Yes: There are randomization techniques for randomized studies that utilize urn models (e.g. Wei's urn design, generalized Friedman's urn model).

Also the lottery, and election fraud verification, those counts as real life right?

how exactly is the polya urn used for election fraud verification and lottery? elections and lotteries both have randomness and the polya urn has randomness ... but what is the connection?

I think this will depend on what you want to count as real life usage. For both cases, the process or parts of it can be modeled as taking draws from urns and deviations thereof point towards manipulation

What about something like vaccine preference? e.g. instead of red and blue balls, you have moderna and pfizer vaccine. A random person in the public is more likely to choose a vaccine that has been chosen by more people, thus further reinforcing?

https://www.nature.com/articles/262646a0 is a fine brief way in to a fascinating literature.

Urn models are used for response-adaptive randomisation in clinical trial, but, as far as I can tell, more in theory than in practice. For example, when we looked at the ANZ Clinical Trials Registry, there were no active trials using urn-based randomisation schemes.
Even when they are used, the statistical analysis typically treats the allocation sequence as ancillary and just works with the total numbers allocated to each treatment.

What about something like vaccine preference? e.g. instead of red and blue balls, you have moderna and pfizer vaccine. A random person in the public is more likely to choose  a vaccine that has been chosen by more people, thus further reinforcing?

In principle I suppose, but I haven't seen models like this and I'm not sure urn models would be a good fit

oh ya? I would be curious to hear why not?

Because an urn model implies that you know instantaneously what vaccines other people got.  I don't have  a problem with the basic idea, I just think urn models will be too simple

I agree with you Thomas, a classic urn model might be too simple. But I thought of this analogy. Some people in the general public might be informed and choose a specific vaccine on purpose. But there might be some people who are less informed - these people still want to get vaccinated, but have no real preference. This group of people might base their choice on the more popular vaccine (i.e. vaccine that is getting more attention in the public, the vaccine that their friends and family took, etc). Thus, vaccines which are more popular have higher probabilities of becoming even more popular

Play-the-winner trials are probably not so often occurring because it requires a sequential randomisation of treatments. Possibly it can be adapted, but then it is still more a sampling with rare experiments with risky ethical considerations such that one wants to optimise the treatments during the experimentation.

With play-the-winner trials, Thomas Lumley gives a direct example where the application is a sampling itself. There is another application which is more indirect, and that is the urn model as an example of a random walk.
That relationship between the urn model and a random walk occurs when by relating each draw from the urn with a walk step forward or backward.
The article in which Pólya and Eggenberger first described the urn model with replacement plus an extra addition has such a random walk application of the model. They used the model to describe the distribution of the cases of an infectious disease (more specifically they looked at the monthly cases of death due to small pox in Switzerland during the years 1877 to 1900).
Polya, George, and Florian Eggenberger. "Ueber die Statistik verketteter vorgaenge." Zeitschrift für angewandte Mathematische Mechanik 3 (1923): 279-289. https://doi.org/10.1002/zamm.19230030407
